# Stream.read() is very slow

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, networkstream, system.net

I have the following code for downloading a file. When i am downloading a file with a browser then it is downloading like 1mbps but when i am downloading with my code it is downloading like 200kbps or so. Why is the code downloading slowly? Is it something due to writing the file every 4096 bytes?

```
private static void DownloadFile(string URL)
        {
            int defaultchunksize = 4096;
            string downloadFolder = GetValue("DownloadFolder"), fileName = Path.Combine(downloadFolder, Path.GetFileName(URL));
            Console.WriteLine("Downloading the file {0} ({1}/{2})", Path.GetFileName(URL), CountOfFilesDownloaded + 1, ListOfFilesDownloaded.Count);
            if (!Directory.Exists(downloadFolder))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(downloadFolder);
            if (File.Exists(fileName))
                File.Delete(fileName);

            ///get cookie 
            string sTmpCookieString = GetGlobalCookies(psarm.Url.AbsoluteUri);//call InternetGetCookieEx
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            HttpWebRequest hwrRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
            hwrRequest.CookieContainer = GetUriCookieContainer(new Uri(URL));
            hwrRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36";
            using (WebResponse response = hwrRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                using (Stream sDataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite(fileName))
                    {
                        byte[] bytesInStream = new byte[defaultchunksize];
                        int read;
                        do
                        {
                            read = sDataStream.Read(bytesInStream, 0, defaultchunksize);
                            if (read > 0)
                                fs.Write(bytesInStream, 0, read);
                        }
                        while (read > 0);
                        fs.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            sw.Stop();
            CountOfFilesDownloaded++;
            Debug.WriteLine("Successfully Downloaded File \"{0}\" from \"{1}\" and time taken to download is: {2}", fileName, URL, sw.Elapsed);
            Debug.WriteLine("\nDownloaded file saved in the following file system folder:\n\t" + downloadFolder);
            Console.WriteLine("Finished downloading the file: {0}", Path.GetFileName(fileName));
            Console.WriteLine("Time took to download: {0}", sw.Elapsed);
        }
```

Comment: Use a higher `defaultchunksize`, but remember, slower connections maybe don't get all of your bytes and will timeout. But in this century, I think 16k bytes as chunksize is normal.

Comment: @ChristophKn i had increased `defaultchunksize` to 512 kb then the performance degraded even more.

Comment: What's the latency on the connection like? And are you using ssl/https? HttpWebReqeust has known throughput issues over https.

Comment: @Tratcher it is http only no ssl. The same file i can download via internet browsers like chrome with really good speed on the same machine and network.